# Select all previous elements within a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div id="whatever">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
<div id="whatever2">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
```

And I need to select with jQuery all the previous spans from the one that I hover within the same div.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**prevAll()**](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to achieve this.

> prevAll() - Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PUyED/1/) example.

---

Here's the code from that example:

**jQuery:**

```
$('span').hover(function(){
  $(this).prevAll().toggleClass('previous');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.previous {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var span = $('div').prev().children('span');
```

Comment: That will select ALL the spans within the div, I want to select all the spans within the div that are previous to the one I'm hover :(

Comment: can you edit ur question and give us the output so we can understand u well

Comment: i think zenith got the answer

Answer (score 0):

You'd use jQuery's [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method to select the previous element. In this case, `#whatever` is the `#whatever2`'s previous element.

```
$('#whatever2').prev();
```

To select the elements within that, you'd then simply use jQuery's [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method:

```
$('#whatever2').prev().children();
```

To do this on the hover of the spans in the `#whatever` divider, you can use:

```
$('#whatever2').on('mouseover', 'span', function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent(); // #whatever2
    $parent.prev().children(); // The span elements within
});
```

**Edit:** Based on comments on another answer I've misunderstood the question. This answer is relevant to anyone who wants to select *all* elements within a previous container.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here i have made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4DmqU/

code is here

html -

```
<div id="whatever">
 <span>1</span>
 <span>2</span>
 <span>3</span>
 <span>4</span> 
</div>
<div id="whatever2">
 <span>1</span>
 <span>2</span>
 <span>3</span>
 <span>4</span>
</div>
```

css -

```
span{
 width:100px;
 height:20px;
 background :#ccc;
 float:left;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

js -

```
$('span').hover(function(){
 $(this).prevAll('span').css('background','#000');
});
```